# Android SQLite libraries

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm looking for a good SQLite library for Android, that makes life easier when handling database operations.

I found two candidates by now:

- [SQLbrite by Square](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite)
- [Sugar](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/)

Do you know any other libraries? Perhaps using your own implementation?

Comment: https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this :-

- [Active android](http://www.activeandroid.com/)
- [Realm for Android](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/)